# Control key is being held after changing language

Tags: xubuntu, shortcut-keys

I've bound <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> to swap languages in Xubuntu. After each swap (randomly) the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is being held (like me pressing Control, but I'm not!) and it won't be fixed unless I press Control key once.

This has started to be annoying, is there any way to stop this behaviour?

**setxkbmap -query** results

```
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us,ir
variant:    ,
options:    grp:ctrl_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll
```

Comment: can you run `setxkbmap -query` and update your question with the results?  did you use the gui settings panel to set that or something else?

Comment: @quixotic Added setxkbmap results.
Yes I've used the GUI settings to bind the keys.